# Grails 2.5.6 JSON response really slow

Tags: json, grails, render

Using Grails 2.5.6 and jdk1.8.0_102. Debugged db fetch time, it's under 500 ms and converting the domain objects to JSON is under 1ms. Response size is about 60KB and running it localhost, so network latency is not an issue. So it all comes down to this:

`render domainObjects as JSON takes 20 seconds
render domainObject as JSON takes 1 second`

And as I wrote, eq. this takes under 1ms:

`def json = domainObjects as JSON`

So the problem is in render. How in earth to make it faster?

Comment: Are you rendering to a UI?

Comment: I think that I've analyzed the same issue some time ago. `def json = domainObjects as JSON` just wraps the `domainObjects` as a JSON-Object but does not convert it into string. I believe that `def jsonString = (domainObjects as JSON).toString()` would take the same 20 seconds as `render` does.

Comment: Yep, toString() was the culprit and just used GSON and response was 300 ms :). And no, I was not rendering to UI.